# Passing function argument as string stored in variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basically, how do I pass in argument into ggplot via a variable?  For example,  let's say I want `scale_arg = 'labels = comma,'` to be passed into `scale_y_continuous` where sometimes it takes that value and sometimes it's just an empty string, depending on whether I want the ggplot to have that arg or not.  How exactly do I pass in argument, stored as string in a variable, into ggplot?  Simply doing `scale_y_continuous(scale_arg)` doesn't work

Example below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

g <- ggplot(data3, aes(x = yrmo, y = weight, color = store)) +
    geom_line(na.rm = TRUE) +
    scale_x_date() +
    scale_y_continuous(
      limits = c(0, 10),
      breaks = seq(0, 10, 1),
      labels = comma,
      expand = c(0, 0)
    )
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your data by adding the output of `dput(data3)` to your post

Comment: Sorry I'd have to make up data, but mtcars is fine.  It doesn't really matter what data since this isn't a data-specific charting question.  It's more how do I make any ggplot function, like `scale_y_continuous` read in arguments that are stored as string?

Comment: Can you edit your code to use `mtcars` package?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do.call`, which passes the elements of a list to a function as arguments. If you run the code below  with `label_arg <- list()`, the result will be what you'd expect without the extra `labels` argument. You could probably figure out a way to pass the argument as a string, but that would be a very non-R pattern.

```
library(scales)

scale_args1 <- 
  list(
    limits = c(0, 10)*1e4,
    breaks = seq(0, 10, 1)*1e4,
    expand = c(0, 0))

label_arg <- list(labels = comma)

scale_args <- unlist(list(scale_args1, label_arg), recursive = F)


ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width*1e4,
                      color = Species)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE) +
  do.call(scale_y_continuous, scale_args)
```

Sidenote to anyone reading this: Is there a better way to combine lists in R than `unlist(list(list_1, list_2), recursive = F)`? Like, a `cbind` but for lists?

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the argument in a *named vector*, like `scale_arg` below. The *name*, in this case `labels`, is the name of the argument you want to keep in the variable.

```
scale_arg = c(labels = 'Sepal Width Label Test')

g <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,
                      color = Species)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 10),
    breaks = seq(0, 10, 1),
    scale_arg,
    expand = c(0, 0)
  )
g
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if you use `scale_arg = c(labels = scales::comma)`

Comment: @Tung In the dataset `iris`, what would be the equivalent to `comma`?

Comment: @Tung OK, got it. Actually, it does "work", it plots the function as y axis label. I don't suppose this is what is expected. Can you be more clear as of what variable goes into `scales::comma`? The `y` variable?

Comment: The expected behavior is that commas are added to the y-axis tick labels (if those tick-labels are > 1000).

Comment: @RuiBarradas: to see the difference better, you can test with `labels = scales::percent` directly in `scale_y_continuous` & your approach which will be `scale_arg = c(labels = scales::percent)`